# grab a value of input from td table

Tags: jquery, html

Please check the jquery code bellow. I want to grab value of class named- `ASINtext` input value. Which user will input the value once dom is loaded. I already tried to do this on line- `var foo = $row.find('td:eq(10)')["0"].children["0"].value;` but the problem is this throws undefined error. How can i fix it? Whats wrong i am donig?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".nfSave", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var foo = $row.find('td:eq(10)')["0"].children["0"].value;
    $row.find('td:eq(10)').html("<img src='/images/loading.svg'  style='width:50px'/>");
    console.log(foo);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="https://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/183725768434-0-1/s-l250/p.jpg" style="width:100px"></td>

      <td><a href="https://www.ebay.com/itm/183725768434" target="_blank">Wilco Distributors 31004 Ground Squirrel Bait, 4-Lbs.</a></td>
      <td>11 Mar 2019</td>
      <td width="6%">$ 38.32</td>
      <td width="4%">108</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="tdforscript" style="display:none"></td>


      <td>
        <div class="UI-Input"><input type="text" id="173517855723" class="ASINtext" value="" style="height: 35px; text-align: center;" placeholder="ASIN">
          <div class="UI-InputBorder"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="UI-Input">
          <select class="listselect" style="height: 35px;">
            <option selectid="9002" value="9002">Lister Integration</option>
            <option selectid="21230" value="21230">UK products</option>
          </select>
          <div class="UI-InputBorder"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button value="183725768434" class="tableButtonDefault nfSave" style="padding:5px!important" data-sold="108"><i class="fas fa-save fa-lg"></i></button>

      </td>
      <td style="display:none">183725768434</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: $row.find('.ASINtext').val();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the input value like this:

```
var input_value = $(this).closest("tr").find('.ASINtext').val();
```